# Destructing an object of a class correctly

Tags: c++, object

I have a scenario, where I draw multiple graphs in same applications and each graph is an object of graph class.

I want to delete the graph using event handling (button click event) and the event handling occurs in graph class and here I can simply call the destructor to delete this object.

Is there a way to tell the main class, from where I am creating these objects, about this event so that all this object references can be deleted?

Comment: See also the discussion on StackOverflow at [Object destruction in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403055/object-destruction-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can simply call the destructor to delete this object.

No, you can't.

If you are in a member of a class, and you want to destroy that class's instance, calling `this->~ClassName()` is a *terrible idea* that will almost always break.

Oh, this will call the class's destructor. But it will not destroy the *memory* associated with that class instance. So that memory allocation will leak.

If you are in a member of a class, and you are ***absolutely certain*** that this class instance was allocated with `new ClassName` (and not `new ClassName[3]` or `new(someMemory) ClassName` or `ClassName varName`), then you can perform `delete this;`.

> Is there a way to tell the main class,from where I am creating these objects, about this event so that all this object references can be deleted ?

Well, you haven't said much about the nature of your system. You seem to have some "main class," and you have some "graph class". And you state that, when the "graph class" is destroyed, the "main class" needs to be notified so that "object references" can be "deleted" (ie: classes need to be destroyed).

If that's the case, then it seems to me that your problem is that this system has unclear ownership semantics. When one object has ownership over another object, then the destruction of the owning object will cause the destruction of the object being owned by it. Value containment (ie: non-pointer member objects) have this ownership relationship with the objects that contain them. Members of a class are destroyed when the class they are a member of is destroyed.

If these "object references" are objects that need to be destroyed when a graph is destroyed, then the graph should *own* those objects. And therefore, the graph *itself* should be responsible for destroying them. In C++11, such ownership relationships are usually expressed by classes like `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

So the graph object shouldn't have to inform anyone of anything. It should be responsible (uniquely or shared) for deleting them.

If these "object references" are just pointers you need to null out (because destroying the graph destroyed the objects they point to), then you have three choices:

1. Remove these "object references" pointers from the main class. Non-owning pointers are dangerous when your code's ownership semantics are muddied. And yours are.
2. Have the graph's destructor inform the main class that these objects are about to be destroyed. This would be done by getting a pointer to that class and calling a function.
3. Have the graph use `shared_ptr` ownership of them, which allows the main class to use `weak_ptr`s as their "object references".

Comment: Thank you @Nicol for the detailed explaination. I think this would help. I will post which solution worked in the end.